Напоминание уважаемым участникам о том, чем является сайт Stack Overflow
Хотелось бы напомнить уважаемым участникам о том, над чем мы все здесь трудимся в поте лица. Это  создание библиотеки детальных, высококачественных ответов на любые вопросы по программированию.
Ещё раз: Библиотека. Высококачественных ответов.
А не ларёк с хот-догами, "подошел, получил в зубы вчерашний фаст-фуд, проходи дальше, не задерживай очередь".
Ларёк в данном случае - это только источник вопросов. Без него не обойтись. Но он не должен замещать библиотеку.
Библиотека - это место, где уже есть готовые ответы, удобно структурированные так, чтобы их можно было легко найти. Чтобы легко найти свой вопрос, он должен иметь адекватный заголовок, который легко находится поиском. А чтобы ответ был полезными, он должен конкретно отвечать на поставленный вопрос, причём только на него.
Исходя из этого определения, можно легко вывести несколько правил участия

SEO. Всегда очень важно следить за тем, чтобы заголовок вопроса соответствовал ответу. Если вопрос дебильный, то его следует закрыть и в идеале удалить. Если заголовок "как сделать", а внутри на самом деле "все сделал, но не работает", то следует отвечать именно на вопрос "как сделать", а не "у тебя опечатка в слове assett".
Как именно следует закрывать вопросы, являющиеся дубликатами

Ищем поисковиком похожий вопрос
Берем самый популярный
Используем ссылку на него для закрытия
Смотрим ответ. В случае, если там типичный треш, написанный в 1918 году недоучившимся школьником, который заметил опечатку в исходном вопросе, то следует исправить этот ответ на нормальный.


Вопрос, которому больше месяца - это уже не клиент у ларька с хот-догами. А фонды библиотеки. Что там имел в виду автор, какие у него были нелепые проблемы - уже никого не интересует. Если вопрос бессмысленный и не привлекает трафика, то либо оставить в покое, либо удалить; eсли привлекает - исправить как вопрос, так и ответ.
Отношение к так называемым "референсным вопросам", в которые сваливаются ответы на миллион совершенно разных, никак не связанных между собой вопросов: ну если прям очень хочется, то создавать такие топики можно. Но следует понимать, что это занятие чисто для себя. Ни в качестве библиотеки (поскольку найти там ничего невозможно), ни в качестве источника для закрытия вопросов как дублей (поскольку они не содержат конкретный ответ) их использовать, конечно же, нельзя.


«исправить этот ответ на нормальный» / «исправить как вопрос, так и ответ» — и отлететь в бан за правку, противоречащую намерениям автора

@andreymal можете пример привести, где именно правка (а не разборки по её обсуждению) послужила причиной бана?

@Kromster наверно хорошо что не могу) Но всё же, поскольку текущая справка сайта намекает, что так делать нельзя, я бы не исключал такую вероятность

@andreymal то есть пруфов нет. И во всяком случае, если противоречат намерениям, то можно добавить свой вопрос и ответ отдельно )

@Kromster это не будет иметь смысла. Вот есть вопрос, который задали в 1918 году, и с тех пор гугль гонит на него трафик. Ну напишете вы свой вопрос с ответом... И его увидят полтора человека, а гугль продолжит гнать трафик на старый. Если популярная книга в библиотеке обветшала, её надо либо отреставрировать, либо заменить на новую. А не оставлять памятником самой себе.

вы путаете разные вещи, я отвечал не вам )

@Kromster Ипатьев любит в своих правках чуть ли не полностью переворачивать смысл, так что не путает

Бугага))) Цитата 1: Библиотека. Высококачественных ответов. Цитата 2: Если вопрос не привлекает трафика, то ... удалить Вы уж определитесь там, чего вы хотите: либо ценные ответы, либо популярные.  Это совсем не одно и то же.  Ценные ответы в малопопулярных областях будут привлекать мало трафика.  Короче, при вашем участии в такой "библиотеке" останется только донцова )))

@ESkri согласен, при желании можно было прочесть этот пункт и так. Поправил.

т.е., призываете удалять ответы, которые кажутся модераторам бессмысленными?  я видел много случаев, когда модератор не видел смысла в вопросе, в теме которого он не разбирался.  лучшее, что вы можете сделать для сохранения библиотеки - не пытаться её улучшить.  потому что сделаете только хуже.

@ESkri рекомендую ознакомиться с принципами работы Stack Overflow, в частности, обязанностями модераторов.

не понял вашу мысль.  что там меня ждёт неожиданного?

Субъективизация правил и демагогия. Не стоит эта тема внимания. А автору подумать, что версия ответа от 1918 может быть много полезней новомодных решений. Есть правила, которые разрешают/запрещают или не оговаривают. Читайте, пользуйтесь и будет вам счастье, так и  модерация контента будет на высоте)

@Dmitry а кто спорит с тем, что версия ответа от 1918 может быть полезной-то? Вы бы сначала прочли текст, перед тем как его комментировать :)

мое прочтение такое, точка. То, что вы пытаетесь тут обсуждать не несет никакой полезной нагрузки. Вот основная мысль моего возмущения. Чем вам не нравится положение дел описанные в справке? Или вас беспокоят не "высококачественные ответы"? Зачем все по 100 кругу из пустого в порожнее гонять? А такие понятия которые вы используете как "недоучившийся школьник" или "ларек" очень субъективны. Пример: первые шаги в модерации вы тоже были "недоучившимся школьником" или вы не погрешими и святы. Расстраиваете вы меня =)

Спасибо за напоминание, но все же часть из перечисленного - это ваши домыслы, а не правила:

Если заголовок "как сделать", а внутри на самом деле "все сделал, но не работает", то следует отвечать именно на вопрос "как сделать", а не "у тебя опечатка в слове assett".

Весьма сомнительное утверждение. Если у автора почти рабочий код, и проблема только в опечатке, надо вопрос закрывать, зачем вообще отвечать. Если же там не опечатка, а неправильное использование языка/библиотеки, я считаю, в ответе следует разобрать как раз эту ошибку, а не механически отвечать на вопрос "Как делать?".

Смотрим ответ. В случае, если там типичный треш, написанный в 1918 году недоучившимся школьником, который заметил опечатку в исходном вопросе, то следует исправить этот ответ на нормальный.

Если ответ просто исправить, автор может откатить правку из-за несогласия с ней. Лучше минусовать и добавлять новый ответ, тогда и репа будет капать автору правильного ответа, а не "школьнику".

Если вопрос не привлекает трафика, то либо оставить в покое, либо удалить.

Почти любой старый вопрос без ответа не привлекает трафика, это не значит, что на него нельзя отвечать. Вполне нормально отвечать на заброшенный вопрос, если знаешь ответ, возможно, что вместе с ответом появится больше ключевых слов, и трафик с поисковиков увеличится.

Отношение к так называемым "референсным вопросам", в которые сваливаются ответы на миллион совершенно разных, никак не связанных между собой вопросов

Это какие, например? Что-то вроде "Как находить ошибки в программах на JavaScript?"

"автор может откатить правку из-за несогласия с ней" - тогда с ним надо провести воспитательную работу, натыкав носом в лицензию, под которой он размещал свой ответ, и которая позволяет кому угодно "делать ремиксы, видоизменять, и создавать новое". Плюс такие эгоистичные говнюки встречаются относительно редко, и их закидонами можно пренебречь.

"следует разобрать как раз эту ошибку" - без проблем. Но тогда надо отредактировать заголовок, чтобы было "как победить такую-то ошибку", а не "как сделать". Вас самого не бесит, когда вы находите такой же вопрос как у вас, а внутри какая-то левота, вызванная чаще всего вообще не связанная с проблемой в заголовке (только сегодня переименовал вопрос "как сделать", а внутри "у меня вообще код не выполняется")

@Ипатьев Лицензия разрешает видоизменять любым образом, создавая свое произведение на основе исходного текста. То есть можно скопировать текст себе на сайт и изменить его как угодно, указывая ссылку на источник. Редактирование исходного сообщения на сайте регламентируется не лицензией, а правилами редактирования, и там есть формулировка, что нельзя менять смысл сообщения.

Я не силён в юридическом крючкотворстве, но если бы лицензия работала так, как вы говорите, то у нас не было бы одной статьи в Википедии с 100500 правок, а было бы 100500 статей, каждая из которых базируется на предыдущей. Лицензия та же самая.

@Ипатьев Если проблема в заголовке, проще исправить его, да. Если что-то совсем левое, вроде ошибок компиляции, надо исправлять, если оно другое, но по теме, это не так важно. То есть если вопрос "Как отсортировать массив?" а в ответе "Вы возвращаете неправильное значение из функции-условия", можно  оставить и так, как минимум, ищущий увидит почти рабочий пример кода сортировки.

Смысл любого ответа на этом сайте - дать качественный ответ на заданный вопрос. Изменение смысла - это написать "Услуги бани и сауны, звоните 222-333-333". А если ответ на вопрос остается ответом на вопрос, но более качественным, то и смысл остаётся тем же самым. Надо определиться, для чего этот сайт. Тешить эго когда-то один раз зашедшего студента, или сделать библиотеку детальных и качественных ответов, полезную людям.

@Ипатьев У Википедии та же лицензия, но отличаются другие принципы: одна статья без определенного автора, нет голосов, репы. На SO в каждом вопросе несколько ответов, у каждого свой автор, можно поставить одному плюс, а другому минус, отсюда и другие требования к правкам.

Но это напрямую противоречит декларируемым целям! На той же странице тура по сайту написано, "SO - это не дискуссионный форум". Но что тогда эта куча ответов, зачастую дискутирующих друг с другом, если не форум? :) Впрочем, мы говорили за лицензию.

Геймификация (баллы) и конкурентность - одни из столпов SO.

@Kromster, их сделали столпами, чтоб завлечь программистов, но заостряясь на этом аспекте - алчность и желание быть первым приводит к тому, что порой и правда, ===> лишь бы больше ответов, лишь бы больше балов, я выше всех в рейтинге...а вон тот, со стаТысячами так сказал, значит это правда, а вон у него авторитет ...// столпами их сделали, чтоб поощрять, чтоб не совсем за зря как бы...но идея это библиотека на будущее

@Dev18 по собственному опыту и наблюдениям, примерно после 3000 (и открытия соответствующих им прав на площадке), баллы теряют особый смысл

может и правда порой стоит редактировать старое, и условно студенту Ивану, который уже не заходил на ресурс с 1918 года пойдут балы, нежели создать новое...я как то нашла вопрос в поисковике, и он был старый, но поисковик его находил, я попыталась изменить, чтоб польза была, (редакцию не приняли) я создала новый вопрос, свои балы получила, система такая.... Но что то в этом однозначно есть, редактировать старое, чтоб обновиться и почистить/привести в порядок то, что уже впринципе не нужно тому, кто писал.

Если автор против, конечно, не трогать, но есть совсем старые вопросы, и ответы на них, поисковик их выдает. и тот, кто писал это вопрос/ответ не заходит давно...поправить в лучшую сторону, история правок все равно всем видна...если не утрировать ситуацию, то идея однозначно прекрасна. Это все равно что взять старое в доме починить(что долговечное и лучшего качества)нежели купить новое одноразовое.(сравнение немного слишком, но идея в том, что поисковик выдает старые вопросы, я видела на en.SO, что так они и делают и пишут комменты, исправил, потому что поисковик его (вопрос)больше выдает)

@Kromster эти столпы превращают SO в помойку

@Ипатьев отнюдь. Они достаточно умело спроектированы для поощрения желаемого поведения и результата, что мы отлично видим по прошествии 10+ лет - SO стабильно в топах по всем программерским вопросам.

Вот только приходя из этого топа хватаешься за голову. Потому что внутри адов треш, который никто не трогал все эти 10+ лет.

Вот пока не доходят у SE руки до того, чтобы это как-то улучшить .. видимо не настолько страшна помойка, насколько страх лишиться её ))

@Ипатьев: Сайт даёт возможность писать отдельные ответы, а не только редактировать общими усилиями один общий ответ. Я лично не против, когда мой ответ улучшают, но если человек пишет нечто, ухудшающее (с моей точки зрения) ответ, я откачу его правку, а если он будет упорствовать, то применю тревогу. Впрочем, эти рассуждения чисто гипотетические, поскольку обычно достаточно написать «ваши изменения противоречат сути моего ответа, так что если вы хотите дать принципиально другой ответ, пишите его отдельно от меня».

@Ипатьев: Это не противоречит тезису о том, что на сайте много ответов низкого качества. Но просто многие (включая меня) считают уж свои-то ответы хорошими. А надзорный орган, который выносил бы вердикт, какой ответ хороший, а какой плохой, тут заменён на голосование. С очевидными плюсами и минусами (pun intended).
